# Problems encoding template

Tags: citing, templates, input-encodings

im new in latex and I'm writing my thesis in english using this brazilian-portuguese [template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/dissertacoes-slash-teses-do-iag-slash-usp/pxzwxzqszhxh)  (for formating reasons) but i'm having two problems:

First, I'm getting tooo much errors when switching to the englsih version (encoding and other issues).

Second - the portuguese version is ok to work, but i don't know how to modify the citations (cause they are in portuguese, and I  need then in english( exemple  I need to get "Angrist and Imbens (1995)" -en - insted of  "Angrist e Imbens (1995)" - pt.

How can I modify this tamplate to do this simple task?

Comment: Welcome to TEXSE, it is too hard to guess your errors without concrete examples. Therefore, please provide a MWE that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Hello @Raaja, thanks for the the welcomes. The enconding errors can be simply seeing by opening the "tese.tex" file (the main tamplate tab), uncommiting the first line and commiting the second one, in other words, using "\documentclass{iagtese_en}". If I could change the just the citations to english standard my problem would be solved while in "portuguese mode".

Comment: The rest of the template documentation is written in english

Comment: For English citations, just use `biblatex-abnt`.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the first error, and, consequently the second one, the english template encoding was on latin1. I just changed it to utf8x

Comment: Don't use utf8x, just utf8

Comment: @daleif i'm curious, why?

Comment: The utf8 part is the one being actively maintained by the latex kernel team. The x version might have had its uses back in the day, but it is no longer the case

Answer (score 0):

Note that typesetting conventions do vary from language to language. E.g. in Spanish a paragraph starts with an indented line, quotes are written '<< ... >>'. Writing English in a template for Brazilian won't come out right.

Comment: Check how firm the demand is. E.g. here theses *must* be in Spanish... even so, many of our theses involve external entities, who handle only English. Also, the official format is geared towards typewriter text, it is just politely ignored...